# Android - What is the difference between kitkat webview and previous version webview?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am developing an hybrid application and installed it on `4.1` and `4.2.2` it works fine. But HTML contents will display very small in `Android KITKAT 4.4`. 
What could be the reason?
What is the work around for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082941/android-webview-with-kitkat-4-4

Answer (score 2):

Android Older version OS web view  has replaced its original Web Kit-based Web View with modern Chromium web view.

The new (chromium based) Web View is faster – so far no surprise. But looking at the numbers, the performance has really increased in several areas (like up to 354% for HTML5 Canvas or 358% for some JavaScript test). So your Web View content should run way smoother and faster then before.

Also take care, that this has been tested on two different OS versions, meaning the improvement might not only be the WebView implementation, but also changes in the operating system. Since the chromium WebView was first introduced on Android 4.4 (at least without rooting devices) the results are in my opinion still showing what performance increase you can expect – at least if you don’t root your device and enable chromium based WebView preversion in pre Android 4.4 devices.

Finally we have the ability to debug remotely Android native webviews –including PhoneGap apps- and the Android Browser and it works smoothly both from real devices and from the emulator. When we have an Android app opened with a web view or the Android Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Different android version differ in webviews as google is always upgrading them in each version. as per your question i say it is not an issue but more like  because of device resolution.