# Titanium Web View Shows a Gray Strip below the Web Page on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, android-4.4-kitkat, galaxy

We are showing a web view in our mobile app. When it is loaded in Samsung Galaxy S4, it shows a grey strip below the page.

[image]

We have tested in iPhone, Galaxy S3 etc. they load the web view correctly. Is this a problem in the Titanium web view or the remote web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this for future reference for anyone.

This happens due to a change happened in 4.4.x version of Android. http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html I think because of this reason, Titanium web view is fails to render HTML properly.

There are lot of issues related to this.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/162279/android-442-webview-height-is-zero
[WebView Rendering Issue in Android KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675554/webview-rendering-issue-in-android-kitkat)
[Android Webview with KitKat 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082941/android-webview-with-kitkat-4-4)

I managed to fixed this by changing my web page according to the migration guide.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I found the root cause of some other(cookies) problem of the WebView on 4.4 thanks to the linked resources.